# Popup message box if certain criteria are met

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on building a cost sheet. Each of the cost line items I put in will have a validity date on which the cost needs to be updated. I am trying to get a message box to popup to notify me when a cost is past it's validity date. In my spreadsheet the validity date is on  "Quote Sheet" in column D and I have the actual date on the sheet "Data Entry" in cell B2. I also have check boxes to select which cost items you want included which when selected populate column Q with a True or False. What I am looking to do is do a macro that will run when an item is selected. So the wording would go something like, "If column Q = True and if column D is less than cell B2 on "Data Entry" then MsgBox "Price is out of date!"" I also have subtotals which will have blanks for the date so I would need something saying if column D is blank then disregard. Thanks for any help! I found the below online and tried it but it didn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Only run if change made to D3, and D2 and D3 are not = ""
If Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If Range("D:D").Value < Sheets("Data Entry").Range("B2").Value Then
MsgBox "Cost is out of date!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: StackOverflow will work much better for you if you post your code attempts first. Then we can help steer you in the right direction so that your code works as you want it to.

Comment: You may want to rethink your approach. This would be fine if there's a VERY small amount of potentially out of date costs, but with more than a few, message boxes will become very intrusive. Not only that, but it will pop up a message every time the worksheet changes which happens more than you may think. This could lead to many redundant messages. I'd suggest populating a column with the address of cells that are out of date instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a condition to your first IF construct to check for blank cells, and Range("D:D") in your second IF construct to Target:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Only run if change made to D3, and D2 and D3 are not = ""
If Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

If Target.Value < Sheets("Data Entry").Range("B2").Value Then
   MsgBox "Cost is out of date!"
End If
```

Comment: I also need for it to check column Q for the value TRUE because I want this to activate when I select a checkbox

Comment: @JamieWalker: This is not freecoder.com! aardbark123 provided you with a solution that give you a good direction. Adding this additional condition should not be so hard for you! Give it a try and come back if you get stuck!

Comment: I understand that but that was the main problem I was having was not being able to do two if statements together. And I have been working on this trying to find different ways to do it because this still isn't working.